# convert text box value (12000) to time format (1:20:00) in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a project which has simply one text box and some sort of buttons acts as numeric input, This is my question : when I enter a number like 12000 into the text box, it suddenly changes the format to 1:20:00 and display in same text box. can it be handled by Text_changed (event handler)? if yes what is code behind ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Isn't there a Format property on the textbox which you can set to a datetime format?

Comment: Yes it is, but the text of text box changes rapidly , I mean sometime 1:20 then 12:00 and 1:12:59. it is not meet my expectations

Comment: If you want to show a time why not use a [TimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/date-and-time)